# mysql trigger to add or subtract from in-stock quantity, subtract 1 when item hired & add 1 on when item return

Tags: mysql

Hi Im having a problem with my mysql trigger syntax, I want it to update my copy_instock row on NEW transaction_id, when movie is hired to subtract 1 from copy_instock, then update when movie is returned to add 1 back on to copy_instock. OR how can I achieve this in a different way from MySql.
My table is below and my trigger that is not correct

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `hires` (
`transaction_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`movie_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`customer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`hire_cost` double(4,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '3.00',
`date_hired` date DEFAULT NULL,
`days_hire` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`date_returned` date DEFAULT NULL,
`total_cost` double(4,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`copy_instock` int(3) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;



CREATE TRIGGER update_instock AFTER INSERT ON hires
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
if (date_returned != NULL) {
UPDATE hires SET (NEW.copy_instock = OLD.copy_instock - 1)
}
Elseif (date_returned != date) {
UPDATE hires SET (NEW.copy_instock = OLD.copy_instock + 1)
END
```

Comment: bad idea. what if someone does `update hires set copy_instock=50 kajillion`, and you only had 3 in stock before? now you've got 50 kajillion + 1 as the stock value. the trigger should simple update the original value +/- 1, not take the updated value and modify that.

Comment: once set say 5 copies, I want it then to be automatically adjusted when hired and returned. That's the reason i want this trigger to eliminate human error as you commented. I'm doing this as an assessment in web dev dp.course. thanks for the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set de delimiter

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER update_instock AFTER INSERT ON hires
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
-- your code
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: #1363 - There is no OLD row in on INSERT trigger-  Thats the error Im getting, I think I need a function to populate the copy_instock from previous min total for that paricular movie being hired first then apply this trigger, because it is blank when creating new record and I think thats why its now giving me no OLD row error

Comment: How do you want to obtain copy_instock when a row is inserted?

Comment: "SELECT movie_id, MIN(copy_instock) FROM hires" that give me all movies hired and copy_instock. Thanks

Comment: now I think I need another trigger when I insert new record I choose a movie and it will populate the copy_instock for that particular movie automatically and return new copy_instock value. Is there any other way to achieve this.

Comment: When you have a table for movie I think its best to have that column in that table, and then update THE column after insert on hires

Comment: Thanks Gervs I will try and/or I will give up on this idea :)

Answer (score 0):

There should be no `{` and `}` in the code. Correct syntax is:

```
IF ... THEN
    ...
ELSEIF ... THEN
    ...
END IF;
```

Also something != null will retrun wrong values, it should be:

```
something IS NLLL
```

or

```
something IS NOT NULL
```

[Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html)

I don't know, if this is what you tried to achieve, however it has corrected syntax:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_instock AFTER INSERT ON hires
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (date_returned IS NULL) THEN
        UPDATE hires SET NEW.copy_instock = OLD.copy_instock - 1;
    ELSEIF (date_returned IS NOT NULL) THEN
        UPDATE hires SET NEW.copy_instock = OLD.copy_instock + 1;
    END IF;
END
```

Comment: edited, my answer - you cannot use ( after set and there should be ; after updates

Comment: its giving me this now ----#1363 - There is no OLD row in on INSERT trigger

Comment: I think I need a function to populate the copy_instock from previous sum first then apply this trigger, because it is blank when creating new record and I think thats why its now giving me no OLD row